# How to go about using tangents in Java?

Tags: java

I was bored and wanted to practice my java coding skills. I made a program that finds the area of a polygon based on what you know (radius, perimeter, apothem).

Here's a portion:

```
static void pentagon() {
    System.out.println("Select what you know");
    System.out.println("[1]Perimeter\n[2]Apothem\n[3]Radius");
    info = input.nextInt();

    if (info == 1) {
        System.out.println("What is the perimeter of the pentagon?");
        double per = input.nextDouble();
        double apothem = per * .137638192;
        double answer = apothem * per * .5;
        System.out.println("The area of the pentagon is " + answer + " square units.");
    } else if (info == 2) {
        System.out.println("What is the apothem of the pentagon?");
        double apothem = input.nextDouble();
        double per = apothem / .137638192;
        double answer = apothem * per * .5;
        System.out.println("The area of the pentagon is " + answer + " square units.");
    } else if (info == 3) {
        System.out.println("What is the radius of the pentagon?");
        double rad = input.nextDouble();
        double per = rad / .1701301617;
        double apothem = per * .137638192;
        double answer = apothem * per * .5;
        System.out.println("The area of the pentagon is " + answer + " square units.");
    }
}
```

Due to the problem that all those decimals (ratio of apothem to perimeter) I had to figure out myself, I could only code a few useful ones.

If I knew how to use tangents, I could figure this out.

Ex: double apothem = length / tan(360/10/2)

(An apothem of a decagon)
Can someone show me how to code the previous line?

Comment: are you sure that's the correct equation?  quick search says 1/ 2 tan(180/n).  you're missing that extra 2 * tan in the denominator

Comment: I tried your method and all I get is negative decimals

Comment: I thought I saw something about java.lang.Math using radians instead of degrees

Answer (score 1):

The recomended way would be to use `java.lang.Math.tan(double a)`

```
double apothem = 1 / java.lang.Math.tan( (2*java.lang.Math.PI)/(10*2))
```

unless there is some reason why you need extraordinary precision and this does not provide it. Then you may be able to find some third party alternative.

Comment: I used your method and I fixed some stupid error I made and I get negative numbers every time from both you and the other dude.


    double apothem = 1 / java.lang.Math.tan(360.0 / 10.0 / 2.0);


turns out to equal -0.8792648757786926

Comment: Everything in `java.lang` is automatically visible in your program, so you almost never need to include that part explicitly.  Just `Math.tan` is good enough.

Comment: You could also use `Math.toRadians()` which is probably easier to read.

Comment: Not if you use a static import of java.lang.Math.PI

Comment: Bear with me because I do not know radians yet. The sample I gave you should be 1 / tan(18) in its most simple form. If you could add the code that equals 1 / tan(18) that would be amazing.

Comment: My major question is what happened to the 360?

Comment: Ok I have a simpler way for me to not be confused out of my mind. Say that the degree in the tan() would already be calculated. Ex: double degree = 360 / sides / 2. then all im asking for is the code 1 / tan(18).

Comment: @CobyWalters The trig functions in Java, like in most computer languages, work with radians, so if you want to use them you will have to know at least a little about them.  The compiler will not understand if you try to say something like `Math.tan(18)` because you don't know about radians. The compiler doesn't know that you mean this in degrees.  You have to convert to radians, using `Math.toRadians()` or using the formula that 360 degrees = 2π radians.

Comment: By the way, `java.lang.Math.PI/10*2` is π/5, not π/20.  You need more parentheses.

Comment: I started with the provided formula at the time (cut and paste) and forgot "2*PI". I was not concentrating on the correctness of the original formula and didn't notice the correction `10*2` -> `10/2`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#tan%28double%29) class which has all the trig functions along with other useful constants like e and PI

So the apothem of a decagon where each side was `length` long and the equation `= length/ 2 tan(180/ n)` would be (after importing the Math class by putting at the top of your java file `import java.lang.Math;` )

**EDIT**
As user ajb points out, `Math.tan()` takes radians so you have to convert degrees to radians so you have to use `toRadians()` to convert from degrees to radians:

```
 double apothem = length / (2 *Math.tan(Math.toRadians(180/10))
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of that by researching other posts. I didn't exactly understand what those answers were doing, so I asked for a line of code that would essentially do this:

Comment: double apothem = 1 / tan(360/10*2);

Comment: `Math.tan` takes an argument in radians.  `Math.toRadians(d)` will convert degrees to radians for you.